Is there any way to change the color of line (trajectory) that appears in the SLAM once the robot starts moving using ROS2 and Nav2?
I want to change this pink line in the image below. I'm using ros2, SLAM and nav2.


Yes, check the rviz display, it should be easy to set the value you'd like.

I think you will find the answer here: rviz/DisplayTypes/Path






Name
Description
Valid Values
Default




Color
The color of the line
([0-255], [0-255], [0-255])
(25, 255, 0)


Alpha
The amount of transparency to apply to the line
[0-1]
1



